# SQL: Fetching one row across a link table join

Tags: sql

Imagine I have two tables, `food` and `people`, and I indicate who likes which food with a link table. So:

```
foods
-----
sausages
pie
Mars bar

people
------
john
paul
george
ringo

person | food (link table)
-------+-----
john   | pie
john   | sausage
paul   | sausage
```

I'd like to get a list of foods, along with **a** person who likes that food. So I'd like a table like this:

```
food     | a randomly chosen liker
---------+------------------------
sausage  | john (note: this could be "paul" instead)
pie      | john (note: must be john; he's the only liker)
Mars bar | null (note: nobody likes it)
```

Is it possible to do this in one query?

Obviously, I can do:

```
select
    f.food, p.person 
from
    food f inner join link l
        on f.food = l.food
      inner join person p
        on l.person = p.person
```

but that will give me *two* `sausage` rows, because two people like it, and I'll have to deduplicate the rows myself.

Comment: I'd store food_id and person_id instead in the link-table. (Store a name only once, in food or people table. Store id's everywhere else.)

Comment: @jarlh I am actually storing IDs in the link table; the above is simplified to make it easy to read. :-)

Comment: Can't you add the id-columns to your sample data? With those you need double join!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `LEFT JOINs` to also get food that no-one likes. `GROUP BY` to get each food only once, use `MIN` to pick first person that likes that food.

```
select f.food, min(p.person)
from food f
    left join linktable l on f.id = l.food_id
    left join people p on p.id = l.person_id
group by f.food
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select f.food, min(l.person)
from food f
    left join link l on f.foods = l.food
group by f.food
```

Comment: You need aggregate function for p.person in the select list.

Comment: You need to remove that single `p.person`, also, just keep `min(p.person)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant.. (Assuming it is SQL Server )

```
Select 
   a.Food, b.Person 
from
   foods a
outer apply
(
    Select top 1 Person from linkTable b where a.Food = b.Food
) b
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a **partition** to do that, example:

```
WITH ORDERED AS
(
    SELECT 
        PERSON,
        FOOD,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lower(FOOD) ORDER BY lower(PERSON) DESC) AS RN
    FROM
    (

        SELECT 'john'  AS PERSON ,'pie'     AS FOOD FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 'john1' AS PERSON ,'sausage' AS FOOD FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 'john2' AS PERSON ,'sausage' AS FOOD FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 'john3' AS PERSON ,'sausage' AS FOOD FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 'john4' AS PERSON ,'sausage' AS FOOD FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 'john5' AS PERSON ,'eggs'    AS FOOD FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 'john6' AS PERSON ,'sausage' AS FOOD FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 'dada'  AS PERSON ,'sausage' AS FOOD FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 'paul'  AS PERSON ,'sausage' AS FOOD FROM DUAL

        -- Your select statement here that links the two tables

    ) PERSON_FOOD

)
SELECT
    FOOD,
    PERSON
FROM
    ORDERED
WHERE
    RN = 1
```

This will get you the following:

```
FOOD     |  PERSON
-------------------
eggs     |  john
pie      |  john
sausage  |  paul
```

This is in oracle syntax